# I do not understand this substring behavior . Rather trivial but it boggles my mind

Tags: c++, stdstring

```cpp
string A = "LOLWUT";

cout << A.substr(0, A.length() - 1) << endl;
cout << A.substr(1, A.length() - 1) << endl;
```

This code prints:

```
LOLWU
OLWUT
```

From my understanding, it should be:

```
LOLWU
OLWU
```

Why? What am I missing? It's a simple thing that I came across while at work today, and I can work around it, but I would like to understand it.

My g++ version:

> g++ (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0

Comment: Out of curiosity, what resource has led you to the conclusion you have stated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument is not the index at which to stop copying, it is how many characters to copy starting at the first argument.

https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! It is this little detail that I was missing! Thank you very much, friend!

Comment: @Carrot13 If this answers your question, you should press the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Different languages and in some cases different libraries have different second arguments for substringing; it's very easy to mistake your memory on what an arg is. So help you if they're named ambiguously.

Comment: Thank you for all the input. Yes, I should have RFTM more carefully. I totally missed that little detail and it is on me. I appreciate your helping me learn.